# list all c files in sub directories and their parent directory

Tags: bash

Assume I have a directory tree as follow:

```
/home/xen/p.c
/home/dan/t.c
/home/jhon/l.c
...
etc (many more users)
```

I need to get comma separated (username,full path to c file) list as follow:

```
xen,/home/xen/p.c
dan,/home/dan/t.c
...
etc
```

How to do that from command line?

Comment: If user have multiple `.c` file, how will it printed?

Comment: user restricted to have only one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to format the output using GNUfind. Assuming files are created by the user itself your command would be:

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.c' -printf '%u,%p\n'
```

See `man find` for more details on `printf`

You could also use the following

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.c' -exec bash -c 'n="${1%/*}"; n="${n##*/}"; echo "$n",$1' _ {} \;
```

Comment: %u give my user name! but I need the last directory name xen, dan etc

Comment: Probably because you are running `find` as a normal user. You cannot access files on anothers home directory. put `sudo`  or `su -c 'find.....'` in front of the command.

Comment: fixed it. but i cannot get the last directory name. is ti possible?

Comment: @tomato Can you be more specific? What is `last directory name` in this case?  If the files are created by the user itself and the username is most likely equal to the `home directory name` then this find command will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in /home/*/*.c
do
echo $i|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $3, ",", $0;}'
done
```

This may help.

Or on a shorter form

```
 echo /home/*/*.c | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";RS=" "}{printf "%s,%s\n",$3,$0;}'
```

where

- `echo /home/*/*.c` will expand (provided you have the right), all .c files
- awk

  - `BEGIN{FS="/"}` will use / as filed separator
  - `{printf "%s,%s\n",$0,$3;}` and print whole line ($0) and file ($3)

Comment: this is better. but still getting home/xen/1.c , 1.c
home/dan/1.c , 1.c
home/john/6.c , 6.c

Comment: getting what msg?

Comment: change $3 to $2 would fix it. @tomato

Comment: either `/home/*/*.c` and $3 --or-- `home/*/*.c` and $2. I would suggest first solution, which is directory independent.

Comment: Did you forget the leading / in the for loop?